# How to change "date modified" of multiple folders, to be the same of that of a .mkv that's inside each one, using Cygwin

Tags: shell, files, timestamps

How to change "date modified" of multiple folders 
to be the same of that of the .mkv that's inside each one.

eg. 
there's folder1 which contains a file 1.mkv

```
folder1: 2/17/14
1.mkv: 1/6/12
```

I want folder1 to get "date modified" 1/6/12

there's also

```
folder2: 20/9/13
2.mkv: 1/1/10
```

I want folder2 to get "date modified" 1/1/10

etc

Maybe some modification of this touch command from
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1526
would help?

```
touch -r **/*(Dom[1]) .
```

(I can't understand what it does)

Here are some sample paths (using Cygwin of course):

```
Kostas@Kostas-pc /cygdrive/f/movies
$ ls -l

drwx------+ 1 Kostas None     0 Feb 18 17:03 Serpico (1973)
drwx------+ 1 Kostas None     0 Feb 21 01:13 The Rite (2011)
```

eg

```
Kostas@Kostas-pc /cygdrive/f/movies
$ ls -l The\ Rite\ \(2011\)/
total 5730596
-rwx------+ 1 Kostas ???????? 5867505504 Apr 27  2011 The Rite (2011).mkv
-rwx------+ 1 Kostas ????????      12968 Feb 16 20:03 The Rite (2011).nfo
-rwx------+ 1 Kostas ????????      79757 Apr 26  2011 The Rite (2011).srt
-rwx------+ 1 Kostas ????????     264745 Oct  8  2011 The Rite (2011).tbn
-rwx------+ 1 Kostas ????????     255667 Oct  8  2011 The Rite (2011)-fanart.jpg
```

Comment: What is the exact name of the .mkv file? Is it not always the same name?

Comment: No, every folder contains a different .mkv file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The switch to `touch`, `-r` uses whatever file you provide it as a reference for what timestamp to use. So for example:

```
$ touch -d 2012-01-01 file1
$ ll
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jan  1  2012 file1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 20 14:37 file2
```

Will set the date on `file1` using the date 2012-01-01. I can the use that file's timestamp to change other files & directories.

```
$ touch -r file1 file{2..5}
$ ll
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml    0 Jan  1  2012 file1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml    0 Jan  1  2012 file2
```

So you could utilize the `-r` switch to do what you want.

#### Example

Say I had the following:

```
$ ll
total 12
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Feb 20 14:42 dir1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Feb 20 14:42 dir2
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Feb 20 14:42 dir3

$ ll *
dir1:
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Jan  1  2012 1.mkv

dir2:
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb  1  2012 2.mkv

dir3:
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Mar  1  2012 3.mkv
```

Now if we run this command we can take the corresponding `.mkv` for each of those directories and use it's timestamp, applying it to each parent directory.

```
$ for i in dir*; do mkv=${i/dir/}.mkv; touch -r "$i/$mkv" "$i" ;done
```

The results:

```
$ ll
total 12
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Jan  1  2012 dir1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Feb  1  2012 dir2
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Mar  1  2012 dir3
```

#### EDIT #1

Based on your example file structure I'd use the following command:

```
$ for i in *;do touch -r "$i/${i}.mkv" "$i";done
```

#### Example

```
$ ll
total 8
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Jan  1  2012 Serpico (1960)
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Jan  1  2012 The Rite (2011)

$ ll *
Serpico (1960):
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 20 18:17 Serpico (1960).mkv

The Rite (2011):
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 0 Feb 20 18:17 The Rite (2011).mkv
```

*apply timestamps*

```
$ for i in *;do touch -r "$i/${i}.mkv" "$i";done
$ ll
total 8
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Feb 20 18:17 Serpico (1960)
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Feb 20 18:17 The Rite (2011)
```

In this scenario, all the `.mkv` files would have to have an identical name to the directory that they're inside of. You'd run this script while inside your `/cygdrive/f/movies/` directory.

Comment: Please, tell me, how in your command
to define the path of the folder in which the subfolders containing .mkvs exist.
In my case, there are in /cygdrive/f/movies.

Comment: @user3231411 - can you give me more of a sample of your directory structure? Is it `/cygdrive/f/movies/folder*`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. eg. 
`/cygdrive/f/movies/movietitle1 (1985)` or
`/cygdrive/f/movies/movietitle2 (1990)`, etc
and each folder contains various files, one of which is the movie_title_something (year).mkv

Comment: @user3231411 - can you do me a favor and include a couple of these directory paths + file names in your Q? Without seeing this it's next to impossible to provide you a more detailed answer.

Comment: Yes, of course.
I just posted some sample paths
(it's via Cygwin, because I use Windows)

Comment: @user3231411 - see updates. LMK if that works.

Comment: It worked like a charm!
Thank you so much for your help and all the detailed posts!

Answer (score 2):

```
for dir in /path/dir1 /path/dir2; do
    mkv="${dir}/.mkv"
    if [ -f "$mkv" ]; then
        touch --reference="$mkv" "$dir"
    fi
done
```