# Recursively update all Folder "Date-modified" timestamps to date of newest file

Tags: date, timestamps, recursive

I would like to recursively update the Date Modified field of a directory (and all its subdirectories) so that every folder has the same Date Modified timestamp as the most recently modified file that is contained within the tree.

I have read and tried to utilise the detailed solutions posted here:
[How do I change folder timestamps recursively to the newest file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/how-do-i-change-folder-timestamps-recursively-to-the-newest-file)
but am unable to get them to work.

I am using Mac OS.

Comment: I finally managed to make the linked solution in zsh work:
`for d in /"YourCompleteFilePathHere"/**/*(/); do touch -r $d/*(om[1]) $d; done.`

The important part was to make sure the entire filepath was specified. `cd`ing into a directory does not change the path of where this script initiates.

However, I find that I need to run the script multiple times for all folders to get updated (the folder tree is highly nested, so perhaps that is the problem). Cheers!