# change last modification date for many files using references

Tags: files, backup, date, timestamps, touch

I have performed a backup and on restoring it, unfortunately, all file access times were set to the timestamp of the DateTime of this restoring process.
How now to set all timestamps from the backup (say `/mount/backup/user`) with the same folder directory structure into my current system (`/home/user`), but only for the files I have not changed after the backup? (at the 11/January/2021)

Somethin with [touch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118577/427268)'s reference option?

```
$ man touch
-r, --reference=FILE
              use this file's times instead of the current time
```

Comment: You'll need to walk the directory hierarchy (perhaps with `find`) for older files (perhaps with the `-mtime` directive) and touch the corresponding backup file (with something like `-exec sh -c 'for file; do bkp=${file/#\/home/\/mount\/backup}; touch ...; done' _ "`)

Comment: What backup software are you using? How did you restore the backup? Are the modification timestamps even stored in the backup? What Unix are you using?

Comment: see my answer, where I explained that I was using Backup using Tar as it is explained on the ubuntu website (see my answer below). when restoring individual files or folders (by extracting them), the file times are lost. This is not the case when restoring complete backup

Comment: IMHO, essential information like that should be in the _question_, which would make it possible to actually answer the question.  For that we know, from reading the question, you're using a proper backup tool such as `restic` or `borgbackup`, not an tape archiving tool or file transfer utility.

Comment: If you're using `tar` to extract individual files from a `tar` archive, it's unclear what you do to reset the `mtime` timestamp (you don't show what command you use).  GNU `tar` extracts the `mtime` stored in the `tar` archive and won't reset it unless you use `-m`.

Comment: I disagree. Independent of what backup tool was used, it happened, that the timestamps were reset, so the question is just about how to restore them. For that purpose, all information are available (the fact that the timestamps are reset).

Comment: It seems to me that if you re-did the restore from backup, but correctly, you'd get the correct timestamps. I can say nothing more about this because I can't see how you did the restore the first time and I don't know what your backup is.

Comment: @Kusalananda and it is not relevant either, as I have explained in my starting post "same folder directory structure". You should answer the question here, or ask relevant details. The solution in the meantime I have found out myself, see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complex statement like this seems to work

```
find . -mtime +225 -exec sh -c 'echo "\n" && echo File = "{}"; bkf="/mount/backup/{}"; echo Backupfile = \""${bkf}"\" . ; test -f "$bkf" && echo do the touch && echo okok ; echo end' \;
```

where 225 is the days between now and the backup (somehow rounded, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25599430/14776523))

The `find`'s `exec` is well described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12904)

**Edit:**
If you have your [Backup archived using tar/tar.gz](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR), you do not need to extract all files, but can simply `cd` to the backup and issue following command ([reference: list tar contents](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/list-the-contents-of-a-tar-or-targz-file/)) to get metadata of all files in the backup:

```
for f in *.tar.gz ; do echo $f; tar -v -t -f $f > "/tmp/contents_backup-20200401/$f.txt"; done
```

(dont know why the -z option was not needed even though the archive was compressed using gzip)

This data is in ASCII table format with space delimied. Unfortunately `cut` cannot operate with variable spacing, but `awk` [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66612752/14776523).

The follwing procedure works smoothly (except some ugly file names with dollar or apostroph signs or brackets). This can be partly fixed by using `fgrep` instead of `grep` but actually it is also find's output by `{}` that is stripped when filename contains for instance a dollar sign or apostrophe.

navigate to the folder of the live system, then:

```
find  *  -type f  -mtime +244   -exec sh -c  'echo "\n" && echo File = "{}"; lastmod=$(stat -c %y "{}" |cut -c-16); echo "LastMod TimeStamp = \""$lastmod"\"" ; dt=$(echo "$lastmod" | cut -c-10) && [ "$dt" = "2020-07-10" ] && ( echo "old file detected" ; timestamp=$(fgrep "{}" /tmp/contents_backup-20200401/backup-musik.tar.gz.txt  | head -n1 | awk -F" " '"'"'{ print $4 " " $5 }'"'"' ); echo "Backup TimeStamp  = \""${timestamp}"\"" . ; test -n "$timestamp" && echo "do the touch" && touch -d "$timestamp" "{}"; echo "ret=$?" && echo okok ) ; echo end' \;
```

whereby:

- `244` is the days from the backup till now (as a first filter)
- `2020-07-10` is the hardcoded date , only files with this date will be affected
- `/tmp/contents_backup-20200401/backup-musik.tar.gz.txt` is the file generated by the above mentioned command

What this command does:

- loop through files in live system
- check if they are affected by a wrong date issue (it is old and was this not altered after the backup, then you dont want to reset its timestamp)
- lookup in the backup listing and find the corresponding entry (this does not work for folders* unfortunately since many files would be found which are in the folder)
- using `awk` get the timestamp of the backuped file
- report about success

*) folder datetimes can be set using [this command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1526/427268) based on the latest file in that folder (actually this needs to be applied to all folders recursively)

```
stat -c %y . && touch -r "$(find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%T+=%p\n' | sort |tail -n 1 | cut -d= -f2-)" . && stat -c %y .
```

Edit2:
escaping ([single apostrophe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)) using correct syntax is sometimes difficult.

Edit3:
This command can be executed in any subfolder which might lead to non-unique matches in the backup lookup, so this will be reported as well:

```
find  *  -type f  -mtime +244   -exec sh -c  'echo "\n" && echo File = "{}"; lastmod=$(stat -c %y "{}" |cut -c-16); echo "LastMod TimeStamp = \""$lastmod"\"" ; dt=$(echo "$lastmod" | cut -c-10) && [ "$dt" = "2020-07-10" ] && ( echo "old file detected" ; filelist=$(fgrep "{}" /tmp/contents_backup-20200401/backup-dokumente.tar.gz.txt); filecount=$(echo "$filelist"|wc -l); echo "file count = $filecount"; [ "$filecount" -gt "1" ] && echo "multiple files found" ; timestamp=$(echo "$filelist" | head -n1 | awk -F" " '"'"'{ print $4 " " $5 }'"'"' ); echo "Backup TimeStamp  = \""${timestamp}"\"" . ; [ $(echo -n "$timestamp" | wc -m) = 16 ] && echo "do the touch" && touch -d "$timestamp" "{}"; echo "ret=$?" && echo okok ) ; echo end' \;
```